# Bulk Save/Update lists of data in MongoDB (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have lists of data which I want to save and if already exist update.
I can do that using loop. But Is there any other way like `insertMany` which only supports insert but I want to insert and update too in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Use updateMany with option { upsert: true } which update the document if it is already exists otherwise insert the new document.

Find below example with restaurant collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Central Perk Cafe", "violations" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Rock A Feller Bar and Grill", "violations" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Empire State Sub", "violations" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Pizza Rat's Pizzaria", "violations" : 8 }
```

The query below update the documents with violations equal to 4 and if the document not exists insert new document.

```
db.restaurant.updateMany(
  { violations: 4 },
  { $set: { "name" : "Eat and Treat" } },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Find more details here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bulk update feature that Mongo driver provides. Instead of invoking the transactions in a loop, you may add them to a bulk transaction and execute as a batch.

First you need to initialize the bulk operation, ordered / unordered:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
```

or

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

Then you can go on adding transactions to the bulk object.

```
bulk.insert( { 
    // attributes 
} );    // insert operation
```

or

```
bulk.find( { 
    // query attributes
} ).update( { 
    $set: { 
        // set attributes
} } ); // update operation
```

In the end you need to call

```
bulk.execute();
```

I don't know if this would serve your purpose.

Please refer this link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/